# Merge two rows in SQL based on a key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table as below:

```
FK | Field1 | Field2 | Feild3
============================
3  | Y    | N        |N
3  | N    | Y        |N
```

I want the result to be like this. please help:

```
FK | Field1 | Field2   | Feild3
================================
3  | Y    | Y          | N
```

Comment: Can you update your post with the reasons why your expected output looks like that?

Comment: Compared to the answers you've got based on your original question (before your changes), you need to either also apply MAX on field3 or you could use GREATEST(field1,field2) with DISTINCT. Anyway, this question is not really meaningful without a detailed explanation. What if further entries occur?

Comment: Please do explain the logic behind the results in words.

Answer (score 2):

```
select fk, max(field1), max(field2)
from your_table
group by fk
```

Comment: max(felid1) doenst give Y with max function

Comment: But it does: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5a3f7/1

Answer (score 1):

```
Select fk, Max(field1), max(field2) from table group by fk
```

In this case you can just use max to return the highest value for each column.